# disallow images to display on gallery

Tags: android, file

I am have downloaded some images into my sd card and i would like to NOT display them in my gallery. Is there a way to remove them? I have read about .nomedia file but how to do I create them?

is it by doing this?

```
            File storagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),folderName+"/Covers/");
if (!storagePath.exists())
{
File file = new File(storagePath, ".nomedia");
if (!file.exists()) {
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
        Log.d("created","successful");
    }
    catch(IOException e) {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: You changed your code (significantly) which makes it hard to give a good answer based on what you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet that will do what you want:

```
    File storagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            folderName + "/Covers");
    storagePath.mkdirs();
    File filename;
    filename = new File(storagePath + "/" + ".nomedia");
    if (!filename.exists()) {
        filename.createNewFile();
    }
```

Note: It might throw an IOException if it cannot create the file, you should catch this.

It will take likely a reboot for the mediascanner to rescan and determine it should not index that location.

Comment: I should place the .nomedia file together in a folder with my images right? Because it doesn't work. it still shows in my gallery

Comment: You will need to reboot the device to force media scanner to scan again, it will not work right away. Or use an app like this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.addz.mediascanner&feature=related_apps#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwOSwiY29tLmFkZHoubWVkaWFzY2FubmVyIl0.

Comment: Also if your gallery app doesn't use the system mediascanner (apparently a few don't) they might ignore the .nomedia file. I don't have any examples but it is possible.

Comment: Then will there be another way to not display the photos? other than downloading applications to help..

Comment: I just told you. The mediascanner runs at boot time. You can try forcing a rescan via your app. Other than that the only way to rescan is with an app. It's not hard to ask your users to reboot, just tell them album art will appear in the gallery until they reboot.

Comment: Okay, I have tried rebooting my device but yet, it still stays in my gallery. is there a problem?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23606/discussion-between-mgamerz-and-user1933630)